# greater than symbol for find() method in php7 mongodb

Tags: mongodb, find, php-7

I am developing a php-mongodb project. I have installed the php-mongodb driver using *composer*. connectivity is working fine.

used reference link for any guidance : 
*http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/tutorial/crud/#crud-operations*
and http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php

I could not find much reliable theory for php-7 except those. 
**How to fire a query with php-7 to get a result from database greater than specified number?**

The code I tried is :

`$rs=$collection->find(['$gte'=>['avg'=>50]]);`

this is not working. The error it produced was:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionException: unknown top level operator: $gte in /var/www/example.com/public_html/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/Find.php:180 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/example.com/public_html/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/Find.php(180): MongoDB\Driver\Server->executeQuery('training.tbl', Object(MongoDB\Driver\Query), Object(MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference))#1 /var/www/example.com/public_html/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Collection.php(437): MongoDB\Operation\Find->execute(Object(MongoDB\Driver\Server)) #2 /var/www/example.com/public_html/list.php(5): MongoDB\Collection->find(Array) #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/example.com/public_html/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/Find.php on line 180
```

Answer (score 2):

found this answer from following [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php)

// search for documents where 5 < x < 20

```
$rangeQuery = array('x' => array( '$gt' => 5, '$lt' => 20 ));
```

for above example the answer comes to be:

```
$rangeQuery = ['avg' => ['$gt' => '50' ]];
$rs=$collection->find($rangeQuery);
```

Comment: I am working with https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.2 but they don't have any example. I was searching and found your answer helpful in that case too. Thanks.